# react-currency-format only shows the last item's price from basket

Tags: reactjs, reduce

I want to calculate the sum of the item prices but it only displays the last item's price.

Here is my code with the react-currency-format:

```js
function Subtotal() {
        const [{basket}, dispatch]= useStateValue();

            
    return (
        <div className="subtotal">
        <CurrencyFormat
            renderText={(value) =>(
                <>
                    <p>
                        Subtotal({basket?.length} items):
                        <strong>{value}</strong>
                    </p>
                    <small className="subtotal-gift">
                        <input type="checkbox" /> this order contains a gift
                    </small>
                </>
            )}
            decimalScale={2}
            value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
            displayType={"text"}
            thousandSeparator={true}
            prefix={"$"}
      />
      <button>Proceed to checkout</button>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is my `reduce` function in *reducer.js*:

```
export const getBasketTotal = (basket) => 
    basket?.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount  , 0)
```

I had an error while installing `react-currency` and i `--forced` it. This is the error:

```
npm i react-currency-format       
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 7.3.0 -> 7.9.0     
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.9.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@7.9.0 to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: your-project-name@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc 
|| ^16.0.0" from react-currency-format@1.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-currency-format
npm ERR!   react-currency-format@"*" from the root project        
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependencnpm ERR! See C:\Users\Programmer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Programmer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-12T07_51_04_200Z-debug.log
PS D:\amazonclone\amazon-clone> npm install react-currency-format 
--save
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: your-project-name@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc 
|| ^16.0.0" from react-currency-format@1.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-currency-format
npm ERR!   react-currency-format@"*" from the root project        
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Programmer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Programmer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-12T07_52_02_519Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your code snippet into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-currency-format-only-shows-the-last-items-price-from-basket-bfjrq) and it seems to function correctly. Can you try creating a codesandbox of your own that reproduces the issue you describe?

Comment: I have a question, while installing react-currency-format it kept erroring and then I installed it with --force to my react. is that a case  that it is the problem?
I think the issue was my react version or something like that
@DrewReese

Comment: I suspect not, it has a peer dependency of `"react": "^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0",` so as long as you are running newer you should be ok. For example, my linked sandbox is running React v17. Do you have any error messages while it's running? Or can you include the error message you saw when trying to install it (along with the command used to install)?

Comment: no erorr, my react is v17.0.2 . 
and the erorr will be conclude in the question

Comment: Great, sounds like you resolved your issue. I'm voting to close as "Unreproducible, or caused by typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I'd made a mistake putting prices in string format and then I put them into {} and problem solved.

Comment: You should look at setting up linting in your IDE - it will help you identify these things faster, and will help you learn good coding habits.
For currency format you could write a much simpler solution with a helper function instead of a React component.

Answer (score -1):

Put your price into braces {} instead of string format

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67072349/2227743).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).